# Ansible, don't specify hosts in playbook and specify hosts via commandline

Tags: ansible

#### Problem

I have a playbook to restore data from a backup. This is a destructive operation that can potentially run on `hosts: all`. So currently my playbook has `hosts: all` in it. 
I'd like to force the user to specify the hosts it wants to restore the backup for so that if the playbook is run without `--limit` option it doesn't work.

#### Question

Is there any way to protect a playbook so that you have to manually specify which hosts to target as opposed to `all`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

Just write in your playbook (example.yml)

```
---
 - name: Limited playbook
   hosts: "{{ target }}"
   tasks:
    - debug:
      msg: "Running on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

Running the playbook would be like

```
ansible example.yml -e target=host1
```

You can also add a default value for target if you want.